# Уточнить значение SQL запроса

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

Есть такой код, например:

```
SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.Score 
From Posts p 
  Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
ORDER BY p.Score desc;
```

Уточните, где можно прочитать\узнать, значение запроса, когда в названия полей и таблиц указываются дополнительные символы (p.OwnerUserId вместо OwnerUserId). Правильно ли я считаю, что **"p."** - это просто возможность указать, из какой именно таблицы брать данные, при условии, если столбцы имеют одинаковое название? Во всех ли БД это применимо? (конкретно Oracle, MsSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL).

Comment: Да, понимаете правильно. Доступно во всех БД т.к. описано в изначальном стандарте SQL. Это называется "Алиасы".

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Уточнить значение SQL запроса](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/930574/%d0%a3%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-sql-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d1%81%d0%b0)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это алиасы (*alias*). Они используются для сокращения записи и разрешния конфликтов имён, если имена столбцов в различных таблицах совпадают. Так как они входят в стандарт ANSI/ISO SQL, то доступны в любой СУБД.

Без них условие соединнеия из примера в вопросе будет также работать:

```
...
FROM Posts  
JOIN PostTags ON PostTags.PostId = Posts.Id
```