# Уточнить значение SQL запроса

Tags: sql

Есть такой код, например:

```
SELECT p.OwnerUserId, p.Id, p.Title, p.Score 
From Posts p 
  Join PostTags t on t.PostId = p.Id 
Where t.TagId = 38 AND p.PostTypeId = 1 AND p.CreationDate >= '2019-01-01' AND p.CreationDate < '2019-01-11' 
ORDER BY p.Score desc;
```

Уточните, где можно прочитать\узнать, значение запроса, когда в названия полей и таблиц указываются дополнительные символы (p.OwnerUserId вместо OwnerUserId). Правильно ли я считаю, что **"p."** - это просто возможность указать, из какой именно таблицы брать данные, при условии, если столбцы имеют одинаковое название? Во всех ли БД это применимо? (конкретно Oracle, MsSQL, MySQL, PostgreSQL).

Answer (score 0):

Да это просто алиас таблицы в общем случае пишется что то вроде

```
table_name AS t
```

так же применимо к имени колонки например

```
column_name AS new_column_name
```

в  таком случае в выводе результата запроса ваша колонка изменит названия на новое, удобно когда новая колонка формируется из результатов различных операций над другими данными

Насколько я знаю применимо во всех обозначенных вами БД